# Round decimals and convert to % in C#

Tags: c#, rounding

I have a list of probabilities like

```
0.0442857142857143
0.664642857142857
0.291071428571429
```

I want to convert them to the nearest  percentages so that the sum of percentages adds up to 100

so something like this

```
0.0442857142857143 - 4 %
0.664642857142857  -  67 %
0.291071428571429  -  29 %
```

I cannot rely on Math.Round to always give me results which will add up to 1. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: In your sample data why does 29 round to 30?  If you multiplied 0.29107 * 100 you would have 29.10% which does not round up to 30.

Comment: What determines which number you round up in case all 3 have a decimal part inferior to 5, like in your example? Why 29 and not 4? It's not the lowest nor the highest.

Comment: 0.2910 does not round to 30% rounding 0.6646 to 67% would have been closer. Is there some other condition that you need to tell us about, so we know when to jump up a %? Is it always the last record or can it be other ones?

Comment: Why the last number gets 30%?
You know that Math.Round has two kinds of rounding number:
1) ToEven.
2) AvoidFromZero.
So which do you actually want? or anything you want in details?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting collection of answers.

The problem here is that you are getting a cumulative error in your rounding operations.  In some cases the accumulated error cancels out - some values round up, others down, cancelling the total error.  In other cases such as the one you have here, the rounding errors are all negative, giving an accumulated total error of (approximately) -1.

The only way to work around this **in the general case** is to keep track of the total accumulated error and add/subtract when that error gets large enough.  It's tedious, but the only real way to get this right:

```
static int[] ToIntPercents(double[] values)
{
    int[] results = new int[values.Length];
    double error = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        double val = values[i] * 100;
        int percent = (int)Math.Round(val + error);
        error += val - percent;
        if (Math.Abs(error) >= 0.5)
        {
            int sign = Math.Sign(error);
            percent += sign;
            error -= sign;
        }
        results[i] = percent;
    }

    return results;
}
```

This code produces reasonable results for any size array with a sum of approximately +1.0000 (or close enough).  Array can contain negative and positive values, just as long as the sum is close enough to +1.0000 to introduce no gross errors.

The code accumulates the rounding errors and when the total error exceeds the acceptable range of `-0.5 < error < +0.5` it adjusts the output.  Using this method the the output array for your numbers would be: `[4, 67, 29]`.  You could change the acceptable error range to be `0 <= error < 1`, giving the output `[4, 66, 30]`, but this causes odd results when the array contains negative numbers.  If that's your preference, change the `if` statement in the middle of the method to read:

```
if (error < 0 || error >= 1)
```

Comment: i really like this implementation . most generic of all

Answer (score 3):

This is an method that could do the job.

```
public int[] Round(params decimal[] values)
{
    decimal total = values.Sum();
    var percents = values.Select(x=> Math.Round(x/total*100)).ToArray();
    int totalPercent = perents.Sum();
    var diff = 100 - totalPercent;
    percents[percents.Lenght - 1] += diff;
    return percents;
}
```

Comment: and it only offsets the last if all :)

Comment: yup, only the last one. I had to use that countless times on reports. Because users must be able to get to 100% when adding the values. Even if this means that the value it's accurate. I had a more elaborated version that would offset the closest value so in the previous case the 66 to 67 and not the 29 to 30,but I don't have the code near me.

Comment: I would have done the same if you wouldn't have posted that. It's not like they are actually going to do the math themselves ... :)

Comment: Does the line  
percents[percents.Length - 1] += diff;
worked properly with out any run time error ?
Please help me out this is throwing me a run time error as
"IEnumerable of decimal does not conatin a definition for Length"

Comment: @Alexandre Thanks this worked fine for me. But it is not working when i have same percentages and the output percentage should round up to 100. Do you have any other solution for this ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

You could just multiply the number by 100 (if you have the decimal number)

```
0.0442857142857143 * 100 = 4 %
0.664642857142857 * 100 = 66 %
0.291071428571429 * 100 = 29 %
```

E: correct, 0.291071428571429  wouldn't add up to 30%...

Comment: It sums up to 99%, not 100.

Comment: you're right... It wouldn't. I was just going by what was given, saying multiplying by 100 would be a method as an example...

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't seem to care which number is bumped, I'll use the last. The algo is pretty simple, and will works for both the .4 edge case where you must add 1 and the one at .5 where you must remove 1 :

1) Round each number but the last one
2) Subtract 100 from the sum you have
3) Assign the remainder to the last number

As an extension method, it looks like this :

```
public static int[] SplitIntoPercentage(this double[] input)
{
    int[] results = new int[input.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        results[i] = (int)Math.Round(input[i] * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
    }

    results[input.Length - 1] = 100 - results.Sum();

    return results;
}
```

And here's the associated unit tests :

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void IfSumIsUnder100ItShouldBeBumpedToIt()
    {
        double[] input = new []
            {
                0.044,
                0.664,
                0.294
            };

        var result = input.SplitIntoPercentage();

        Assert.AreEqual(100, result.Sum());
        Assert.AreEqual(4, result[0]);
        Assert.AreEqual(66, result[1]);
        Assert.AreEqual(30, result[2]);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void IfSumIsOver100ItShouldBeReducedToIt()
    {
        double[] input = new[]
            {
                0.045,
                0.665,
                0.295
            };

        var result = input.SplitIntoPercentage();

        Assert.AreEqual(100, result.Sum());
        Assert.AreEqual(5, result[0]);
        Assert.AreEqual(67, result[1]);
        Assert.AreEqual(28, result[2]);
    }
```

Once refactored a little bit, the result looks like this :

```
public static int[] SplitIntoPercentage(this double[] input)
{
    int[] results = RoundEachValueButTheLast(input);
    results = SetTheLastValueAsTheRemainder(input, results);

    return results;
}

private static int[] RoundEachValueButTheLast(double[] input)
{
    int[] results = new int[input.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        results[i] = (int)Math.Round(input[i]*100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
    }

    return results;
}

private static int[] SetTheLastValueAsTheRemainder(double[] input, int[] results)
{
    results[input.Length - 1] = 100 - results.Sum();

    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Logic is , Firstly we have to round off the "after decimal value" then apply round off to whole value.

```
  static long PercentageOut(double value)
    {
        value = value * 100;
        value = Math.Round(value, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // Rounds "up"
        value = Math.Round(value, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // Rounds to even

        return Convert.ToInt64(value);
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        double d1 = 0.0442857142857143;
        double d2 = 0.664642857142857;
        double d3 = 0.291071428571429;

        long l1 = PercentageOut(d1);
        long l2 = PercentageOut(d2);
        long l3 = PercentageOut(d3);

        Console.WriteLine(l1);
        Console.WriteLine(l2);
        Console.WriteLine(l3);
     }
```

**Output**

```
   4
   67
   29
   ---
sum is 100 %
```